# Github does not display a font defined in a SVG

Tags: github, svg, markdown

I've got an SVG file with a font defined like this:

```
<defs>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: "Virgil";
        src: url("https://somedomain.com/somefont.woff2");
      }
    </style>
</defs>
```

I want to add this SVG to a markdown file stored on Github. So I uploaded the SVG and added the image link to the markdown file. Now Github displays the markdown with the image just fine except the font. Github displays some default font instead of `somefont.woff2` specified in SVG.

Am I missing something ? How can I fix the issue ?
The font URL -- `https://somedomain.com/somefont.woff2` -- works fine for me in my computer.

Comment: SVG when used as an image must be self contained.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Is there any way to "embed" a font in a SVG ?

Comment: Sure, encode it into a data URL assuming the font's licence permits you to do that.

Comment: Hmm ... isn't `src: url("https://somedomain.com/somefont.woff2");` a data URL ?

Comment: [no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Comment: Aha, got it :)) Thanks a lot !

Comment: This may not be possible. As a safety precaution, GitHub strips all `<style>` tags from user provided content that it displays on its site, as documented in step 2 [here](https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup). By using your browser's "view source" or "inspect" tool, I expect you will find that the entire `<style>` tag and its contents have been stripped from your document.